Algorithm extract/select polygons by location with equal predicate does not lead to expected results
I have two polygon layers with around 4000 features. The features are largely the same (geometry and attributes) but there are features that are contained in one layer and not in the other.
I would like to extract or select these features that are only present in one layer (shown in orange in the example image) in order to add them to the other layer.
I used the algorithms select by location and also extract by location with the predicate equal but did not get the expected result. I wanted to select those who are duplicated and then invert the selection to get the features which are not in the second (black) layer.
Only very few polygons (shown in pink in the image) were selected, but many more polygons should actually be extracted, namely all polygons with the black border in the example image.
I also tried detect dataset changes and that did not lead to the expected result either.
A random check of the vertices on the polygons does not reveal any differences in the coordinates.
Does anyone have an idea why it is not working?
Or is there another way?

I chose the styling above to make it clear that many polygons are on top of each other.
Its 3D data, polygons have different z values in their vertices. The polygons were obtained by tachymetric measurements.
If these are filled, then unfortunately it is not so easy to see which polygons are not equal.
I have attached two more images to make it clear. Only the two polygon layer to be compared are shown, without the output of the algorithm (shown with pink filling in the first picture)
In the images below both polygon layers are filled with 30% opacity but unfotunately you can't see anything due to overlapping. I have marked some of the areas where the polygons which are not equal are visible because less polygons are overlapping.

In the last image only one polygon layer is filled (grey with 10 % opacity) and the second layer, which is not congruent, is shown as orange lines without filling, otherwise its hard to see the differences.
Through the transparent filling you can see the orange lines of the features I want to select or extract or rather select all the other to receive the orange ones after deleting or inverting the selection.


Your styling makes it difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Can you show a less messy area? And style the polygons with a fill color so it is possible to see what is inside and outside

Yeah, what Bera writes. You also could provide example data to help us understand the issue.
